# How to delegate NS for the apex?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

We have a registered domain (example2.com) that has the company's name servers registered against it (ns1.example.com, ns2.example.com) at the registrar.

We would like to "delegate" the DNS resolution for the apex itself (example2.com) to different name servers (nsx.aws.com) i.e. we would like example2.com to resolve using these other aws name servers.

Is this possible to do so by configuring the company's name server records to "simply delegate" the resolution of the apex?

Should it be as simple as creating NS records on nsx.example.com for example2.com to point to nsx.aws.com?

Or is the only way to achieve this by changing the NS entries with the registrar of example2.com to nsx.aws.com?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you need the registrar's records to updated so that your records look like this:

```
$ dig example2.com NS

[...]

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example2.com.          IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example2.com.       1795    IN  NS  nsx.aws.com.

[...]
```

Comment: Hi Alexis. Thank you. Is this a DNS spec limitation?

Comment: It is. All NS queries will have to hit the apex so if your registrar does not point to the server you want, that server will never get to serve any queries.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to go through the domain registrar to make this happen properly.

Comment: Hi mdpc, Thank you. Is this a DNS spec limitation?