# DNS shows wrong IP addresses on different machines

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, static-ip

I have a very weird problem when I try to resolve my domain ( wiki.stroeersocialpublishing.de ) with a static IP.

On some machines the DNS shows the correct IP ( 99.81.177.226 ) and on other machines the DNS shows different IPs that are wrong.

It's a 50/50 chance that the IP is correct. The problem is still there even after setting up a new EC2 instance in AWS.

Is this an AWS problem? Because flushing the DNS does not solve this problem.

I don't know if [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/709706/964517) already answers my problem.

An explanation would help me to understand (and maybe solve) my problem.

Comment: What is your domain name, and what IP do you expect? We can't really help without that information. Does your EC2 instance have a public / elastic IP? Are you using a load balancer? What DNS server / service are you using?

Comment: The domain is `wiki.stroeersocialpublishing.de` its IP should be the elastic IP `99.81.177.226` and for the test purposes I used the google DNS `8.8.8.8`. There is no load balancer.

Comment: Can you confirm the behavior by logging onto those machines and run `nslookup wiki.stroeersocialpublishing.de`? That command should print out more about the actual resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Using [DnsChecker](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=wiki.stroeersocialpublishing.de&rtype=ALL&dns=opendns) I can see that major DNS providers (Google, CloudFlare, OpenDNS) report the IP for the domain correctly, as does my ISP. I suspect the problem is with your client.

[image: DNSChecker]

What problem is this causing? Can you not access the domain? Are others reporting a problem? If multiple people are reporting the problem do they all use the same ISP? You could try querying some local DNS providers to see what they report.

[image: MXToolbox]

Answer (score 0):

We figured out the problem. The problem is that our domain has two NS and they return completly random the correct or incorrect IP. It isn't a problem of the client, which DNS, or from which ISP you `dig`. The first NS has the correct IP and the second didn't got the update that we have a new IP address. The second NS thinks that the old IP is still correct.