# Registrar nameservers vs. NS records for bare domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, dns-zone, ns-record

OK, I'm a bit new to DNS, but I'm having some trouble finding the answer to this. I have a domain registered at google domains. As with other registrars, you have access to their free DNS, and although I realize you can change these, I also noticed the option of entering "NS" records (as opposed to other types, e.g. A, CNAME, etc.) for individual subdomains (zones?)--even for the bare domain (e.g. example.com). How does this differ from the registrar's nameservers? Will entering NS records for a bare domain conflict with the registrar's nameservers if you haven't changed them? Or do the NS record ones take priority over the registrar ones? Could someone explain this to me?

Also, if I wanted to use cloudflare for one subdomain only, could I just enter cloudflare's dns servers as multiple NS records for that subdomain, or would I have to change the main DNS servers (away from google, that is.)? Thanks very much.

**Follow up:**
I just did a `dig example.com any` and noticed that the registrar's nameservers show as NS records for the bare domain. I thought that the registrar's DNS server settings were somehow separate from the ordinary resource records (A, CNAME, etc.). I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the role of NS records at the apex of a DNS domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/588244/what-is-the-role-of-ns-records-at-the-apex-of-a-dns-domain)

Comment: It gets a little confusing, for sure. The short answers are: 1) you want your apex NS records to match what you've configured at the registrar for reasons that are elaborated on in the linked Q&A, and 2) NS records below the apex delegate authority to other nameservers, so using Cloudflare for those (without changing your settings at the registrar) is fine.

Comment: RE: your update, they *are* separate. First the registrar NS records are used (more specifically, the glue is used), then once those TTLs expire the records are refreshed against the contents of your zone file on the nameservers you control. I linked something touching upon this already. If you're going to make assumptions on your own without asking for clarifications we can't really help you.